# Unset/remove array elements that form a pair PHP

Tags: php, arrays

There are two arrays, that has say below data -
$a = Array(a,b,d,c,e,a);
$b = Array(a,a,d,e,c,a);

I want to remove an instance of array values as a pair, i.e., it should exist in array 'a' and array 'b'
If you understand, I want to remove elements that form similar pair.

The output should finally be like -
`$a = [b]; $b = [a];` as those are the only elements that left which doesn't make a pair.

I tried using array_diff, but it's not getting me the expected output -

```
$arr1 = array_diff($aArr, $bArr);
$arr2 = array_diff($bArr, $aArr);

print_r($arr1);
print "<br>";
print_r($arr2);

$res = count($arr1) + count($arr2);
print $res;
```

This code is working fine, when the input is 
Array ( c, d, e ) 
Array ( a, b, c )

But will give zero for input as 
Array ( a, a, b, d, e, c, a ) 
Array ( b, a, b, d, e, c, a )

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: are the positions absolute?  As in , if $a has 10 elements then $b has 10 as well and the $a[9] will be checked against $b[9]?

Comment: @Forbs, yeah the size of a and b are absolute.. $a and $b both will have equal no of elements.

Comment: This feels like a coding interview question. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and passing by reference:

```
$a = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'a'];
$b = ['a', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a'];

$a = array_filter($a, function ($element) use (&$b) {
    if (($key = array_search($element, $b)) !== false) {
        unset($b[$key]);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd9d785112e8e3c3dc7a0365e35b1481d2e7f836).

With [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) we can filter array based on predicate function (a function that returns true for elements, that should be kept in the result, and false otherwise). In our case, this function uses `$b` in order to determine to keep a `$a` element or not. If we in clause `$b` by reference, we can remove pairs along the way.

Comment: @sevavieti, your code is working like a charm, but could you also please add some explanation as to what you are doing?

Comment: @KumarAnand, yes, sure no problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This works with arrays of different sizes and disregards values positions.

```
$arr1 = removePairs($aArr, $bArr);
$arr2 = removePairs($bArr, $aArr);

print_r($arr1);
print "<br>";
print_r($arr2);

$res = count($arr1) + count($arr2);
print $res;

function removePairs($a, $b)
{
    $r = array();

    foreach ($a as $index => $value) {
        $found = array_search($value, $b);

        if ($found !== false) {
            $b[$found] .= '-';
        } else {
            $r[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through every array like this

```
foreach ($a as $aItem){
    if(!in_array($aItem, $b)){
        $arr1[] = $aItem;
    }
}
var_dump($arr1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work due to duplicate values.  So (a,a,b,c) and (b,c,a,a) results in an empty array using your function.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered. But the accepted answer is slower than my more complicated solution (if order does not matter).

```
$a = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'a'];
$b = ['a', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a'];
$ha = $hb = [];
foreach ($a as $v) $ha[$v]++;
foreach ($b as $v) $hb[$v]++;

foreach (range('a', 'z') as $l) {
    if (empty($ha[$l])) continue;
    if (empty($hb[$l])) continue;
    if ($ha[$l] > $hb[$l]) {
        $ha[$l] = $ha[$l] - $hb[$l];
        unset($hb[$l]);
        continue;
    }
    $hb[$l] = $hb[$l] - $ha[$l];
    unset($ha[$l]);
}
$a = [];
$b = [];
foreach ($ha as $l => $n) $a = array_merge($a, array_fill(0, $n, $l));
foreach ($hb as $l => $n) $b = array_merge($b, array_fill(0, $n, $l));

var_dump([$a, $b]);
```

Above code is O(N) as the accepted answer is O(N^2). So choose from simplicity or speed.